# Rails Associations - Multiple has_one relationships to the same class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

An example of my issue is a sports game. A sports game has two teams, a home team and an away team. My active record models are as follows:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :game

end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :home_team, :class_name => "Team"
  has_one :away_team, :class_name => "Team"

end
```

I want to be able to access a team through the game, for example: Game.find(1).home_team

But I am getting an unitialized constant error: Game::team. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks,

Comment: If `Team ... belongs_to :game`, a team can only ever play one game. You probably want `has_many :games`

Answer (score 7):

If `Game has_one :team` then Rails assumes your teams table has a game_id column. What you want though is for the games table to have a team_id column, in which case you'd use `Game belongs_to :team`. As English it does sound backwards in this case, but as Ruby, it's correct.

I did simplify a little. You'd want something like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, :class_name => "Game", :foreign_key => 'home_team_id'
  has_many :away_games, :class_name => "Game", :foreign_key => 'away_team_id'
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => "Team"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code and it should work.

What I suspect is that your file name is wrong. Make sure that your filenames in app/models/ are:

- game.rb
- team.rb

and not:

- games.rb

  or
- teams.rb

Answer (score 1):

I think that it may be a mistake of your architecture.

Game can't distinguish two Team with this architecture.

So, please run like that

```
rails g migration add_stadium_to_game stadium:integer
rails g migration add_home_to_team home:integer
rake db:migrate
```

and, edit "game.rb" like that

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :teams

  def home_team
    teams.select { |team| team.home == self.stadium }.first
  end

  def away_team
    teams.select { |team| team.home != self.stadium }.first
  end

end
```

Of cource this is one example, so there are many ways to realize your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a namespacing problem.  Try explicitly declaring the class (with namespace) for team.  E.g.:

```
has_one :home_team, :class_name => "::Team"
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association